# Center bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue centering the dropdown menu buttons. I'm using bootstrap in `ASP.NET MVC 5`.

Here is the html code:

```
            <div class="navbar-center">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">HR Online<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Job Postings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HR Manual</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Im using a div that encompasses the entire dropdown menu. It's class name is "navbar-center"
I can use padding it will work. But I don't believe that is the most effecient way of centering it.

I have used `align-content`, `align-items` and `align-self`. None of them work. Do I have to stick with `padding`?

NOTE: its not the text I want to align, it's the buttons. (The buttons you press before it drops down a menu)

Answer (score 3):

Just use text-align: center the anchors in

```
.dropdownmenu > li > a {
   text-align: center;

}
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/oHwP1hHbnq

Comment: It's not the text I want to align. It's the buttons.

Comment: You mean that you have multiple dropdowns (your example has only one) that you want to center? Wrap them into a container (<div class="container"></div>).